# How to access values by their keys as if processed with num_to_word_dict (if it existed)?

Tags: python, apache-spark

Is there a way to access a value by a key using Apache Spark?

Consider the following simple example, where there are two lists of key-value pairs which I would like to join:

```
num_to_letter = sc.parallelize([(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')])
num_to_word = sc.parallelize([(1, 'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three')])
num_to_letter.join(num_to_word).map(lambda x: x[1]).collect()
```

The result matches the letters to the words of the numbers:

```
[('a', 'one'), ('b', 'two'), ('c', 'three')]
```

The example shows it being done using a join, but it should be much more efficient to actually do this as a map operation where num_to_word is a dictionary:

```
num_to_word_dict = dict(num_to_word.collect())
num_to_letter.map(lambda x: (x[1], num_to_word_dict[x[0]])).collect()
```

The question is, is there a way to create something that acts like `num_to_word_dict` without having to collect the values in `num_to_word`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `def lookup(key: K): Seq[V]` function defined on RDDs of pairs that resolves a key to the list of values associated with that key.
Nevertheless, it will not be helpful in this case because rdds cannot be used in closures and that would be needed if we want to resolve values of a second RDD.

Given that both datasets are RDDs, `join` is a good way to proceed.

If the RDD that contains the resolution association is small enough to fit in memory of the driver and of each executor, the **most** efficient way to to this kind of resolution in Spark would be to create a map as a broadcast variable and map elements of the other RDD in each partition.

```
val numWordBC = sc.broadcast(numToWord.collectAsMap)
val letterToWord = numToLetter.mapPartitions{partition => 
    val numWord = numWordBC.value
    partition.map{case (k,v) => (numWord(k),v)}
}
```

Comment: In my case it is, but what about when the resolution table is not small enough to fit in memory?

Comment: then `join` is your friend. `lookup` will be ridiculously expensive to use for this purpose.

Comment: The problem is that `join` complains about `Too many open files`, and I don't have admin access and can't increase the ulimit so the lookup was a sort of workaround.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question about `Too many open files` then!

Comment: One would think... but it's been asked before and the answer always seems to be 'increase your ulimit'.